# Arrays and bitmaps arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, bitmapimage

I am working on a project where I need to display bitmaps on my 5.0" tft display using arduino gfx libraries. In order to generate these bitmaps, I converted them to byte array and have them stored in another array something like this :

```
const unsigned char* const array[] PROGMEM = {
 one,//one, two, ... are the names of various arrays containing bitmaps
 two,
 three,
 four,
 five,
 six,
 seven,
 eight,
 nine,
};
```

I am using the following function to draw the bitmaps:

```
void make(int x, int y)
{

  for (int i =0; i<=151; i+= 150){
    for (int j = 0; j < 601; j+= 150){

      tft.drawBitmap(x+j,y+i,array[page],100,100,RA8875_GREEN);//page is defined as a global variable

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is if I use a changing variable such as page, the bitmap is not completely drawn
However if I use a constant such as int a = 0; then the bitmap is drawn fully.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the value of page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
  Serial.print("element_arr[alpha]: "); 
  Serial.println(element_arr[alpha]); 
  Serial.print("Patterns : "); 
  arrayA = ((element_arr[alpha] -1)/ 10); 
  Serial.println(arrayA); 
  colourA = (element_arr[alpha]) % 10 == 0 ? 9:(element_arr[alpha]) % 10 -1; 
  Serial.print("ColourA is : "); 
  Serial.println(colourA); 

  if (arrayA == 0){
     tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[0], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }else if (arrayA==1){
     tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[1], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] )); 
  }else if (arrayA==2){
    tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[2], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }else if (arrayA==3){
    tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[3], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }else if (arrayA==4){
    tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[4], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }else if (arrayA==5){
    tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[5], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }else if (arrayA==6){
    tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[6], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }else if (arrayA==7){
    tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[7], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }else if (arrayA==8){
    tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[8], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }else if (arrayA==9){
    tft.drawBitmap(x + j, y + i, array[9], 120, 120, pgm_read_word( &colour[colourA] ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A constant works because the compiler can optimize the array `array` away, and a pointer directly to the 'pointed to array' is used.

When using a variable, `array` is kept, and subsequently put into `PROGMEM`.
This effect you are seeing is a result of not using `PROGMEM` data properly.

You will have to use `pgm_read_word` to extract the pointer properly.

Instead of:

```
array[page]
```

You'll need to use:

```
(unsigned char*) pgm_read_word( &array[page] )
```